# Is there a standard UNIX way of writing <filename> and <lineno> to stderr unambiguously?

Tags: python, unix, logging, standards, gnu

## Statement of Problem

I have an application (python, if it matters) which parses files and may generate errors during parsing. When this happens, I log where the error occurred to stderr and exit gracefully.

As I write locations to stderr, I have to choose between absolute and relative path for the logging.

I need to weigh these between relative paths being short and readable when stderr is the console, and absolute paths being unambiguous when stderr is redirected to a logfile and inspected later.

### What I Have Now

What I am doing now boils down to this

```
def clean_path(path):
    rpath = os.path.relpath(path, '.')
    if len(rpath) < len(path):
        path = rpath
    return os.path.normpath(path)
```

I then format the result as part of

```
<filename>, lineno <lineno>: <message>
```

and write this to stderr or a logfile specified in program config. Typically stderr.

### Lack of Apparent Consensus

I have looked at the GNU standards, http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Errors
, and they do not specify.
They also deviate from the above format, which I have seen elsewhere -- although I cannot now recall where.

GCC always uses the filename passed to GCC, but most of the files I am operating on will be absolute paths for implementation reasons.

Bash interpreter errors don't even specify a file.

I could not find any PEPs that specify a standard for python logging of this kind, but in a quick test, pep8 and flake8 seem to follow the GNU standard.

---

It seems that the GNU Standard is the de-facto standard, but not everyone follows it (surprise!).
Is that actually the case?

Given that most paths I work with will be normalized to be absolute before the error logging code ever interacts with them, would specializing my handling of this be considered poor practice?

Comment: Seems like you've already done a deep research and made your decision. Go for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The GNU *"Standard"* is really just a set of guidelines. However, as you have aptly noticed, not everyone follows it. In fact, I daresay that outside of GNU projects, few care to follow it.

That being said, you seem to have done the research yourself. As there is no common consensus on this topic, I would say to simply make your application easy to use. The decision you appear to have made, to use this:

`<filename>, lineno <lineno>: <message>`

seems fairly reasonable. I would also add the name of you application, the type of error and the code on that line, somewhat like this:

```
<appname>: Parsing Error: <message>
    In <filename>, line <lineno>: <code>
```

Finally, don't write your errors to a logfile (unless the user somehow specifies that they want to; ie: command line option). Instead, write all errors to `stderr`. If the user wishes to, they can manually pipe `stderr` to a file like this:

```
$ python <appname>.py 2><appname>.log
```

which, let's say, your app was called `parser`, would look like:

```
$ python parser.py 2>parser.log
```